# Quantitative factorization of a finite rank operator through $C(K)$, $K$ finite (reference request)

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

Suppose that $E$ is a finite dimensional normed space, $F$ is a Banach space, and $T:E\to F$ is an operator. Is there a way to estimate the infimum of $\|L\|\|R\|$ as $L,R$ range over all factorizations $T=LR$,  $R:E\to \ell_\infty^n$, $L:\ell_\infty^n\to F$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, in terms of some geometric constants (type constants, cotype constants, etc.)? Here, I don't care about how large $n$ is.